# In a UITableView, how do I close the bottom border of a row after hiding the row after it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

Here's what I mean by "close the bottom border":

[image]

The second row is currently "hidden" (its height is set to 0). When the user clicks on the first row, the second row appears (its height is restored). If it helps, here's the code for hiding and showing the second row.

First, I have a member variable that stores whether the second row is open (it's a row with a picker view):

```
var referenceLengthPickerIsOpen: Bool = false
```

Here's how the height is determined:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
           heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return referenceLengthPickerIsOpen ? 216.0 : 0.0
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Here's the code for handling when the user clicks on the first row in order to show or hide the second:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
           didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        referenceLengthPickerIsOpen = !referenceLengthPickerIsOpen
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The showing and hiding part works great, with a nice animation as the second row's height changes from 0 to 216 and vice versa.

However, after hiding the second row, I'm left with the border gap shown in the image above. I know the reason: the bottom border is closed only for the last row, and it's currently hidden.

I've tried to fix this by changing the number of rows like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
      numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return referenceLengthPickerIsOpen ? 2 : 1;
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}
```

But this just crashes my app as soon as I click on the first row.

Comment: I believe that the bottom border may be `UITableView` separator line. Please let me know if it's not.

Comment: This line `referenceLengthPickerIsOpen ? 2 : 1` should do the job normally. Can you show me the crash report so that I can look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to storyboard,select cell go to Separator, custom insets and make it 0. Below is the image.

[image]

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the footer margin for each section also becomes zero, which makes the text be right up against the left edge of the view.

Comment: Not in my example i will post another image.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why my footer's margin changes with the inset. Anyway, the problem with setting the table view's inset is that it affects all rows. I actually want the rows to have an inset, except in the case where the next row is hidden (making the previous row the last row, so it should have a full bottom border).

Comment: If tableView is static, dont do it in the tableview custom insets, do it to tableViewCell. i will add another image showing u another example

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Because I do want the inset when the second row is shown, I dynamically change the inset back to what it was when the second row is shown, and back to .zero when it's hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the bottom border is probably the default separator line of `UITableView`. Setting the `separatorInset` of `UITableView` to 0 should resolve the problem if that's true

You can do it in the following way.

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

The above code closes the bottom border.

You can hide the bottom border by hiding the separator.

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
```

Please let me know if it resolves the problem or not.

Comment: Thanks. It almost works. I set the `separatorInset` to zero in the `viewDidLoad()` method, but it also causes the footer left margin to be zero, so the text is right up against the left edge.